# How to NOT modify an S4 object with a function in R? (flowset)

Tags: r, function, arguments, r-s4

This one is a little bit unusual, I certainly missed something. I have complex S4 objects (flow cytometry data; flowsets), for visualization purposes I would like to modify the column names of some of the dataframe inside the object. I created a function that takes the object as input and apply the modifications. The thing is : even if I apply this function to a copy of my object it will also modify the original. This issue prevent me from doing the next step of the analysis.

```
a=b
c=rename_data(b)
```

This code modifies a.

Answer (score 1):

### From the docs:

> The bulk of the data in a flowSet object is stored in an environment, and is therefore not automatically copied when the flowSet object is copied. If x is an object of class flowSet, then the code

```r
y <- x
```

> will create an object y that contains copies of the phenoData and administrative data in x, but refers to the same environment with the actual fluorescence data

It goes on to explain how to make deep copies (i.e. "proper" copies)

> However, note that subsetting operations, such as `y <- x[i]` do create proper copies, including a copy of the appropriate part of the fluorescence data, as it should be expected. Thus, to make a proper copy of a flowSet x, use `y <- x[seq(along=x)]`

Therefore, in your case, you should do

```r
a <- b[seq(along = b)]
c <- rename_data(b)
```

Now `a` contains the copy of `b` *before* the modifications inherent in `rename_data`